# Got problem with classify function in tensorflow/core

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow

I got this problem in image recognition program. Something went wrong with model.classify function I did not find any solution. But everything works fine in older versions of tensorflow/tfjs-core (I use 4.0.0 but works fine with 1.2.1). Should I use older version or I can fix this problem?
[image: problem]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as mobilenet from "@tensorflow-models/mobilenet";
import photo from "./images/Unknown.jpeg"
function App() {
const [img, setImg] = useState(photo);
const [model, setModel] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    loadModel()
}, []);


const loadModel = async () =>{
    const model = await mobilenet.load();
    setModel(model)
}

const predict = async () =>{
    const predictions = await model.classify(img);
    console.log(predictions)
}

return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={predict}></button>
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just added following lines at the bottom of the index.html in public folder

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-core"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter"</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl"</script>
```